# Viewing the actual desktop on a remote computer

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm running an raspberry pi with a display connected to the hdmi port. With a remote computer I want to view the actual graphic desktop (started with startx) of the pi which one can see on the display.

Is it something with export DISPLAY? But I have no idea about the correct parameters. I have a ssh connection via putty and a RDP connection. But the RDP desktop  I see on the remote computer is different from the desktop of the hdmi display.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using raspbian, install and run x11vnc on the raspberry pi.

You will need to run a vnc viewer on the remote computer to connect to it, you will then be able to see the desktop.